# Chrome DevTools Timeline: New charts

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-performance

In the current Chrome version (46) the DevTools Timeline contains a bunch of new charts. The meaning of most of those charts is not obvious to me. Unfortunatly I could not find any documentation on them either. Can someone explain the meaning of those charts?

[image]

Comment: a bummer with the new version is that the 'frames view' appears to missing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the overview bar on Chrome DevTools Timeline panel.
From top to bottom:

yellow/green ticks are input activity, e.g. mouse moves/click, key press. Each has it's own color. Btw you have to enable a Chrome DevTools experiment to see this bar.

red stripes bar is page responsiveness indicator. If you have a particular issue at some point it shows a red bars. The problems detected include long frames, excessive or forced layouts, etc.

green chart is current frame rate. The higher -- the better. Max is 60fps.

next bar is CPU utilization. The full bar height means 100% CPU is busy. Colors correspond to the type of activity: yellow is JavaScript, purple is style recalc or page layout, green is rendering/painting, blue is html parsing or blocking network interactions.

thin stripes below CPU are network requests currently in flight. Colors depict content type: blue is html, green is media (images, fonts etc), purple is css, yellow is JavaScript, grey is for all others.

Comment: Thanks! Did you figure it out yourself,or can you name any source?

Comment: I think this is the source: (google official devtools documentation) https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool